# How to pass value from field to a wizard in Odoo 12?

Tags: odoo, wizard

I have this field below

```
name = fields.Text("Input text here")
```

And I want to pass its value to the wizard when I click a button. Here's the code:

```
@api.multi
def open_wizard(self):
return {
'view_type': 'form',
'view_mode': 'form',
'res_model': 'customer.wizard',
'target': 'new',
'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
'context': {'current_id': self.id}
 }
```

And here is my XML. But it still didn't work as I expected.

For the button:

```
<button name="open_wizard" string="Submit" type="object" class="oe_highlight" context="
{'name': name}"/>
```

For the wizard itself. I want the value to be on the 'Resi' field:

```
<record id="view_test_report_wizard" model="ir.ui.view">
 <field name="name">Customer Wizard</field>
 <field name="model">customer.wizard</field>
 <field name="arch" type="xml">
 <form string="Choose The Details">
 <group>
 <tree>
 <group>
 <field string="Resi" name="name" context="{'name' : name}"/>
 <field name="tanggal"/>
 <field name="kotaasal"/>
 <field name="kotatujuan"/>
 <field name="id_customer"/>
 </group>
 </tree>
 </group>
 <footer>
 <button string="Back" class="oe_link" special="cancel"/>
 </footer>
</form>
</field>
</record>
```

Do you have any solution? Thank you

Answer (score 3):

you can try this way

```
wiz = self.env['customer.wizard'].create({'name': self.name})

@api.multi
def open_wizard(self):
return {
'view_type': 'form',
'view_mode': 'form',
'res_model': 'customer.wizard',
'res_id': wiz.id,
'target': 'new',
'type': 'ir.actions.act_window',
}
```

or you can pass the value in the context

```
'context': {
   'default_name': self.name,'default_tanggal': self.tanggal
   'default_kotaasal': self.kotaasal,'default_kotatujuan': self.kotatujuan
   ,'default_id_customer': self.id_customer.id
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Just update the context on method `open_wizard` like the following:

```
'context': {'default_name': self.name}
```

That will (virtually) create the wizard with the value of `self.name`.